# How pull xcom variable from previous run

Tags: airflow

How pull xcom variable from previous run in airflow? Is it possible?

I want to use value from same task_id in previous run_id as jinja variable for `data` argument in SimpeHttpOperator.

[image: f]

I'm looking in macros docs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html
and cant't find any documented way to do this.

UPD
Example:

```
select_expired = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='select_expired',
    http_conn_id='clickhouse_http',
    endpoint='/',
    method='POST',
    data=REQUESTED_EXPIRED_FLIGHTS,
    xcom_push=True,
    pool='clickhouse_select',
    dag=dag
)
```

where REQUESTED_EXPIRED_FLIGHTS is:

```
insert into table where column = '{{ ??????? (value returned in previous task) }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the previous task_instance using [`previous_ti()`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.TaskInstance.previous_ti)

Then you can use `get_state()` to get its state, and perform actions based on that.

Comment: Can you provide a little more explanation for updated example in answer?

Comment: Hi Eduard sorry for the delay, I can. Can you provide a larger snippet of your code for me to help?